# error while installing virtual environment

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm following official django tutorial on their webpage. When I run command 
"py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win", I get the the following errors. Please see the screenshot. I have Anaconda installed. The same error occurs on my other computer where I have only Python installed. What am I missing?

C:\Users\Alex>py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrapper-win (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrapper-win

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: First of all there is no screenshot. Second it is recommend to post the error directyl from console rather than posting a screenshot of it

Comment: Please provide screenshot or errors in text

Comment: Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try (for anaconda):

python -m virtualenv env_name

Comment: I did. Nothing happens. No error, just prompts me with the same C:\Users\Alex>

Answer (score 0):

Use the Anaconda prompt terminal.

Comment: Thanks. That worked! Could you tell me why that is? Is it because the python was installed through Anaconda?